# What is the performance of calling CanvasRenderingContext2D's getTransform()?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, webapi

What is the performance/time complexity of calling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform?

I'm using this method a lot inside of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method, so it's called a multiple of 60 times per second.

It says that "The returned object is not live", does that mean a new matrix is created every time this method is called? That doesn't seem fast.

Comment: You can test and compare the performance of any block of JS using this tool: https://jsbench.me/

Comment: Why do you call it multiple times in a single frame? You should call it at most once, and modify the returned object.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't need to modify it, I need some values from it.

Comment: Then you'd certainly win by keeping one instance and applying the same operations on it as you do on your context.

Comment: @Kaiido But doesn't JavaScript have Common Subexpression Elimination?

Comment: JS maybe, but `getTransform()`  will make a call to the rendering engine code (e.g Blink or Gecko, generally C# or Rust), which itself could even make a call to the graphics engine to get that state back (e.g Skia or Cairo). On these calls, the JS engine (V8 etc.)'s JIT can't do such optimization, it doesn't know if the state did change between both calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do some tests https://jsben.ch/Clten

Setup:

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.setTransform(1, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0, 0);

const getTransform = () => ctx.getTransform();

const createAnObject = () => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

const getRandomNumber = () => Math.random() * 5;
```

get transform

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
  const x = getTransform();
}
```

get random number

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
  const x = getRandomNumber();
}
```

create a new object

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
  const x = createAnObject();
}
```

Result:

```
createAnObject (71057) 

getRandomNumber (2430)

getTransform (33)
```

As you can see, it's the slowest of these three, but it's not because it's creating a new object. Creating a new object isn't expensive at all, it's faster than using `Math.random()`

Comment: These kind of tests don't mean much. Running it in Firefox you'll have completely different results, where getRandomNumber is the clear winner. Create a true DOMMatrix and you'll get yet different results, where in both FF and Chrome getTransform is actually faster: https://jsben.ch/61joa

Comment: That's why you always have to test your code on every browser that it's supposed to run on

Comment: No, that's why you should almost never trust micro-benchmarks like this.

Comment: So what should be done instead?

Comment: Test the whole application, search for a bottleneck only if any.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question: `What is the performance of calling CanvasRenderingContext2D's getTransform()?`

Comment: Indeed, but your answer doesn't answer that either. It just says that when running a huge `for` loop like you'll never see in any actual code, that will make the JIT trigger whatever optimization it knows, building an Array is damn fast in V8. That's all your answer says. (I did vote to close that question since it's too broad)